# Cannot find button element on form using Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm having trouble trying to click on on a button within a form.
I've tried xpath, cssselector, className, id, but still cannot find it.

Here's the HTML snippet for the button:

```
<input type="button" value="Continue" id="ni-reg-btn-register" class="btnNext ni-reg-btn-register">
```

I'm using WebDriver in Java

Getting this trace:
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 30.09 seconds

Frequency: 100%

Browser: Firefox

URL: https://subscription.thetimes.co.uk/webjourney/webj_capturecustomerdetails

I've tried each of the following lines of code one by one (but no luck):

```
driver.findElement(By.className("btnNext ni-reg-btn-register")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("buttons#ni-reg-btn-register.btnNext ni-reg-btn-register")).click();
List<WebElement> buttonlist=    driver.findElements(By.className("btnNext ni-reg-btn-register"));
driver.findElement(By.id("ni-reg-btn-register")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="ni-reg-btn-register"]")).click();
```

Comment: If you're getting an ElementNotVisibleException, then the element can't be clicked on. A couple of things you can check. First, and I've seen this a lot, there might be another identical button in the DOM which is hidden that is actually being found instead of the one you want to click on. Check for duplicates. Next check if you need to wait for the element to be visible before clicking on it.  Try stepping through your code and see if you get the same error.

Comment: and now that I've actually looked at the website you provided, I don't see any duplicates, but it could still be a timing issue. Also, since it's a form, you could also try driver.findElement(By.id("ni-reg-btn-register")).submit(); Either way, your selector seems spot on.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to click the `Continue` Button using the below xpath.

```
//input[@id='ni-reg-btn-register']
```

Comment: I added:- driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='ni-reg-btn-register']")).click();   but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying a `WebDriverWait` call to wait for the element in question to exist on the page prior to interacting with it. The Java documentation can be found [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html). It appears that while you are using the correct locator and your page is working, there is a timing issue where Selenium is trying to access the element prior to it being loaded.

EDIT: I was unable to locate an element on the provided page with the supplied *id*. I assume I am missing a step, but I did a search on the HTML for that page and found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I dont find the above button on the page link you provided ..
better chk the page link and try to give some wait statement after page load ...

implicit wait would be better or simpli Thread.sleep(2000);